# async ajax call error won't show Error.cshtml

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a function in the controller using ajax.  If there is an error in the controller, it goes to the Error.cshtml page, sends an error email from that page, but it won't render the Error.cshtml page on the screen, it stays on the page with the ajax call.

How do I fix that?

Here is the ajax call:

```
        $("#County").change(function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCountySessionVariables", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ countyId: $("#County").val() }),
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        },
        failure: function (data) {

            alert('failure');
        },
    });
});
```

Here is the customErrors from the main web.config:

```
     <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"/>
```

Comment: can you step thru the ajax script ..?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax` definition you should use `error` property, not `failure`, check [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Like this:

```
$.ajax({

    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCountySessionVariables", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ countyId: $("#County").val() }),
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('failure');
    },
});
```

You also can get full error page like this:

```
    error: function (httpRequest) {
        console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
    },
```